# is it possible to override the source when using rust command to update

Tags: linux, rust

I am using rustup to update the rust version, is it possible to specify the source in the command line like this?

```
rustup update --source http://rustup.com
```

I already know how to config the mirror url in `.cargo/config`, I just want to switch the source in temporary in the command lne. Seems no way to do this from official document:

```
➜  .cargo rustup update --help
rustup-update
Update Rust toolchains and rustup

USAGE:
    rustup update [FLAGS] [toolchain]...

FLAGS:
        --force             Force an update, even if some components are missing
        --force-non-host    Install toolchains that require an emulator. See https://github.com/rust-
                            lang/rustup/wiki/Non-host-toolchains
    -h, --help              Prints help information
        --no-self-update    Don't perform self update when running the `rustup update` command

ARGS:
    <toolchain>...    Toolchain name, such as 'stable', 'nightly', or '1.8.0'. For more information see `rustup help
                      toolchain`

DISCUSSION:
    With no toolchain specified, the `update` command updates each of
    the installed toolchains from the official release channels, then
    updates rustup itself.

    If given a toolchain argument then `update` updates that
    toolchain, the same as `rustup toolchain install`.
```

Comment: You can set the `RUSTUP_DIST_SERVER` [environment variable](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/environment-variables.html), e.g. `RUSTUP_DIST_SERVER=http://rustup.com rustup update`.